# NSLinkAttribute cancel scrolling when not editable

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

**I have following setup:**

A `UITextView` with some text and some of then are ***links***.

When I set the `isEditable` value to `false` I can't initialize any scrolling when tapping over those **links** that are actionable now.

> **How can I make touch events that start on a link to actually drag the
>   `UITextview` when users do scrolling gesture.**

Answer (score 0):

**To overcome this difficulty the steps are the following:**

Suppose you have a class that inherits from `UIScrollView`, for instance
`RichTextView : UITextView` (as `UITextView` inherits from `UIScrollView`), then you have the property         `panGestureRecognizer`. This property holds designated scroll gesture recognizer.

Next step is creating a **delegate** to assign to this gesture recognizer, lets write needed code:

```
extension RichTextView : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    } 
}
```

so in your init() or when needed just write:

```
panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
```

**Why was happening?**

Child recognizer, in this case the one created to make links tappable are canceling the gesture. So is needed to deliver the gesture to all recognizers simultaneously

For more details, please refer to [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:)